# include wholesale field in mysql query

Tags: mysql, opencart

I am using Opencart 2.2.0. I have two customer groups - default and wholesale customers. Throughout my web site, `price` field is for default group, and `wholesale` field is for wholesale customer group. I also added `wholesale` field in specials tab (to the `oc_product_special` table) and everything works fine(it remembers the value in admin, as well as gets added to cart by the special price for both groups on front end.) My only problem is that it doesn't show correctly on front end. Meaning that it shows value from the special  `price` field for both customer groups, instead of showing `wholesale` special price for wholesale customer. I figured out where the problem is - in the query in `model/catalog/product file`. I would like to know how to alter the following query, so that I can include `wholesale` field, because only then would I be able to show it on front end. My query is:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, **(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,** (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");
```

The part of the query which is for special is:

```
(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem...In case anyone gets stuck in the same place, here is what I did:

I **added another line(subquery) to the query**, where I defined special_wholesale like this:

```
SELECT wholesale FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.wholesale ASC LIMIT 1) AS special_wholesale
```

as well as defined `'special_wholesale' => $query->row['special_wholesale']`, in query array bellow the `'special'` array element in `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` file inside the `public function getProduct($product_id)` function.

After that, I defined `$special_wholesale` variable in controller file for the featured products(`/catalog/controller/module/featured.php`).

The last thing I did was call the  `$product['special_wholesale'];` in featured.php`(/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/module/featured.tpl)` file like this:

```
<font size="2" color="red"> <span class="price-new"><?php echo "VP:" . $product['special_wholesale']; ?></span>&nbsp;<span class="price-old"><?php echo "VP:". $product['wholesale']; ?></span></font></br>
```

The output is: striked out old wholesale price and display of special wholesale price.

I hope this can help someone. Cheers!